# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).shuffle is not a function Jquery Jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

В `xhtml` файле подключаю библиотеки:

```
outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery-1.3.2.js"   
 outputScript library="javascript" name="ui.core.js"    
 outputScript library="javascript" name="ui.sortable.js"    
 outputScript library="javascript" name="indexFunction.js"
```

В `indexFunction.js`:

```
(function ($) {  

    $.fn.shuffle = function () { 
        return this.each(function () { 
            var items = $(this).children(); 
            return (items.length) 
                    ? $(this).html($.shuffle(items, $(this))) 
                    : this;  
        });  
    };  

    $.fn.validate = function () {  
        var res = false;
        this.each(function () {
            var arr = $(this).children();
            res = ((arr[0].innerHTML === "1") &&
                    (arr[1].innerHTML === "2") &&
                    (arr[2].innerHTML === "3") &&
                    (arr[3].innerHTML === "4") &&
                    (arr[4].innerHTML === "5") &&
                    (arr[5].innerHTML === "6"));
        });
        return res;
    };

    $.shuffle = function (arr, obj) {
        for (
                var j, x, i = arr.length; i;
                j = parseInt(Math.random() * i),
                x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x
                )
            ;
        if (arr[0].innerHTML === "1")
            obj.html($.shuffle(arr, obj));
        else
            return arr;
    };

})(jQuery);

$(function () {

    $("#sortable").sortable(); /*для возможности перетакивать*/

    $("#sortable").disableSelection();

    $('.captcha_wrap ul').shuffle(); /*перемешиваем*/

});
```

Следующая ошибка срабатывает:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).shuffle is not a function
```

В файле  `indexFunction.js.xhtml?ln=javascript:392` , т е строка:
    `$('.captcha_wrap ul').shuffle(); /*перемешиваем*/`

До этого на `jsp` было, все работало как надо, а теперь на `jsf` переписывают и такое...

Comment: Попробуйте удалить явный импорт jquery-1.3.2.js и посмотреть, изменится ли что-то. Есть вероятность, что JSF-ский фреймворк импортирует другую версию JQuery. Кстати, не указано, какую реализацию JSF используете.

Comment: После удаления подключения в коде библиотеки jquery - вот такая ошибка: _Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined_. Использую _Primefaces_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что переменная $ к моменту окончания загрузки документа оказывается затерта чем-то другим. Решение проблемы - в том, чтобы найти где можно сохранить ее.

---

Поскольку у вас блоки с объявлениями функций и их использованием находятся в одном и том же файле - надо просто переместить второй блок внутрь первого. Это будет работать, поскольку вы сохраняете $ в качестве параметра автовызванной функции.

Также, если на странице используется другая версия `jquery` - неплохой идеей является использование `noConflict`:

```
(function ($) {  

    $.fn.shuffle = function () { 
        ...
    };

    ...

    $(function () {

        ....    
        $('.captcha_wrap ul').shuffle(); /*перемешиваем*/

    });

})(jQuery.noConflict(true));
```

Если же сделать так не представляется возможным - можно воспользоваться тем свойством jquery, что она передает саму себя в обработчик события готовности документа:

```
$(function ($) {

    ....    
    $('.captcha_wrap ul').shuffle(); /*перемешиваем*/

});

$.noConflict(true); // Обязательно после всех ваших модулей!
```

В обоих случаях, требуется, чтобы ваши модули были подключены сразу после используемых вами же библиотек.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает =) 
`jQuery.noConflict(true)` помогло

Comment: @Наталья боюсь предположить как вы его использовали отдельно от остального ответа...

Comment: Именно так, как вы указали, так и сделала, т е   
`(function ($) {  

    $.fn.shuffle = function () { 
        ...
    };

    ...

    $(function () {

        ....    
        $('.captcha_wrap ul').shuffle(); /*перемешиваем*/

    });

})(jQuery.noConflict(true));`

Comment: @Наталья ну так вам помог не noConflict - а перенос куска кода. noConflict тут не для вашего кода, а чтобы чужой не сломался.

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду. Спасибо за разъяснение :)

Comment: Функция jQuery.noConflict() предназначена не для того, чтобы использовать несколько версий jQuery совместно, а для того, чтобы дать возможность использовать jQuery с другими JavaScript-библиотеками, которые тоже используют глобальную функцию $(), например, Prototype. Есть вероятность появления практически не диагностируемых ошибок в самых неожиданных местах. Отлаживать JSF дело само по себе нелёгкое, а с такими конфликтами версий оно может стать просто безнадёжным. Настоятельно не рекомендую использовать 2 версии jQuery. Даже если сейчас всё работает нормально, в будущем может "сломаться".

Comment: @bobzer если сделать как написано у меня - никаких недиагностируемых ошибок не будет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, боюсь, Вы ошибаетесь. И дело тут не в том, как решить проблему из обсуждаемого вопроса, а в том. что остаётся импорт другой версии jQuery, который может повлиять на функциональность Primefaces. Я думаю, что даже сами разработчики фреймворка Primefaces не могут дать гарантий отсутствия недиагностируемых ошибок в такой ситуации.

Comment: @bobzer как он может повлиять на работу `Primefaces` - если в момент исполнения любого кода `Primefaces` другой версии `jquery` нет в области видимости?

Comment: @PavelMayorov В самом начале вопроса написано "В xhtml файле подключаю библиотеки" и далее список библиотек jQuery. "xhtml файл" - это область видимости Primefaces. Сам фреймворк также делает неявный импорт своей версии jQuery в той же самой области видимости, и обращается к jQuery для выполнения множества различных действий на стороне клиента - в браузере. Какая версия jQuery при этом будет использоваться - неясно.

Comment: @bobzer но не будет же фреймворк добавлять свою библиотеку в середину списка пользовательских библиотек! Он добавит ее в начало или в конец списка. В любом из этих двух случаев мой код успеет "зачистить следы" прежде, чем фреймворк получит шанс сломаться.

Answer (score 0):

`Primefaces` содержит библиотеку `jQuery` в своём составе. Попытка подключить `jQuery` явно может привести к проблемам с её версионностью.

Можно попытаться использовать `jQuery`, поставляемый с `Primefaces`, для чего следует добавить на страницу следующие импорты:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" />
```

Тег `target="head"` нужен только в случае, если импорт осуществляется вне блока `<h:head>`

Если версия `jQuery` из `Primefaces` не подходит, то можно подменить её одним из следующих способов:

1. Переопределить своей версией, осуществив импорт js-файла с именем `/resources/primefaces/jquery/jquery.js`. Путь к файлу и его имя должны быть именно такими, т.е. следует переименовать `jquery-1.3.2.js` в `jquery.js` и создать папку `/resources/primefaces/jquery/` в корневой папке веб-части вашего приложения и сохранить js-файл в ней.
2. Заменить версию `jQuery` в библиотеке `Primefaces`. Распакуйте `primefaces.jar`, замените `/META-INF/resources/primefaces/jquery/jquery.js` новой версией, упакуйте `primefaces.jar`.

Следует тщательно протестировать замену, т.к. может быть нарушена функциональность `Primefaces`. Способ 1 в этом плане более безопасен, т.к. можно осуществить импорт только на конкретных страницах, не затрагивая функциональность приложения в целом (как в способе 2).

Comment: Использование `jQuery`, поставляемой с `Primefaces`, к сожалению не дало положительных результатов. Помогло `jQuery.noConflict(true)`, как посоветовали ниже